# How to implement single sheet menu for fab in android

Tags: android, menu, kotlin, floating-action-button

I want to open a single sheet menu when I click on the fab in an android app. shown in this:
https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_8/material_ext_publish/0B8v7jImPsDi-d09QRUZzVUdMSFk/components-buttons-fab-transition_card_01.webm

But I haven't found a native implementation for this even though it's specified in the material design guide. Any idea how to do it without using third party libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Try this .i think this is best example for material sheet fab . just read and create your own fab sheet.

- [material-sheet-fab](https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab)

Comment: yeah I saw that one. but it hasn't been updated for 2 years and I would like to avoid using external library

Answer (score 0):

This is not like what you want. But maybe this would help your problem another way.

FAB + BottomSheetBehavior

https://medium.com/android-bits/android-anchoring-views-to-bottom-sheet-9c9069caf7d4